# Java Pusher Client disconnects right after connecting

Tags: java, websocket, spring-websocket, pusher

I am connecting to Pusher server using JAVA code and the issue is the client (using Java Client library) disconnects after few seconds of making connection to the server and it does not reconnect itself.

Also, the connection status at the java-client shows is **CONNECTED**, as shown in the onConnectionStateChange() callback method but in the background it seems like it stays disconnected because when I tried pushing a request from the server java client did not receive anything but on reconnect (manually) I get the request.

Code:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class PosWebSocketClient {

private Pusher pusher;

private boolean isConnected = false;

private String pusherAppKey;

private Timer timer;

private Date activeTime;

private boolean isUserLoggedIn = false;

private PusherOptions pusherOptions;

public synchronized void init(String pusherAppKey) {
    log.info("Initializing Pusher");
    pusher = new Pusher(pusherAppKey/* , pusherOptions() */);
    this.pusherAppKey = pusherAppKey;
    this.isUserLoggedIn = true;
    pusher.connect(new ConnectionEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(ConnectionStateChange change) {
            log.info("State changed to " + change.getCurrentState() + " from "
                    + change.getPreviousState());

            if (change.getCurrentState() == ConnectionState.CONNECTED) {
                isConnected = true;
            } else {
                isConnected = false;
            }
            log.info("isConnected {}", isConnected);                
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String message, String code, Exception e) {
            log.info("Error while connecting to the server with {} {} {}", message, code, e.getMessage());
            log.error("Exception: - ",e);
        }
    }, ConnectionState.ALL);


    Channel channel = pusher.subscribe("*****");         
    channel.bind("any-event-1", sendDataListener());
    channel.bind("any-event-2", receiveOrderListener());
    channel.bind("any-event-3", logOutListener());
    channel.bind("any-event-4", getOrderStatusListener());


    activeTime = new Date();
    /*
     * if (timer == null) { timer = new Timer(); timer.schedule(new MyTask(), 0,
     * 1000 * 60 * 2); }
     */
}

class MyTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        long idleTimeInMinutes = (new Date().getTime() - activeTime.getTime()) / (1000 * 60);
        log.info("Pusher Idle Time {} ", idleTimeInMinutes);
        if (isUserLoggedIn && idleTimeInMinutes >= 10 && StringUtils.isNotBlank(pusherAppKey)) {
            log.info("Pusher idle time is greater than 10 mins, initializing again");
            disconnect();
            init(pusherAppKey);
        }
    }
}

private SubscriptionEventListener logOutListener() {
    return new SubscriptionEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(PusherEvent pusherEvent) {
        }
    };
}

private SubscriptionEventListener sendDataListener() {
    return new SubscriptionEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(PusherEvent pusherEvent) {
            log.info("Received SendData event");
        }
    };
}

private SubscriptionEventListener receiveOrderListener() {
    log.info("Received FetchOrder event");
    return new SubscriptionEventListener() {
        }
    };
}

private SubscriptionEventListener getOrderStatusListener() {
    log.info("Received SendStatus event");
    return new SubscriptionEventListener() {
        }
    };
}

public synchronized void disconnect() {
    // Disconnect from the service (or become disconnected my network conditions)
    if (pusher != null && pusher.getConnection() != null) {
        log.info("Disconnecting Pusher");
        Channel channel = pusher.getChannel("*****");
        channel.unbind("any-event-1", sendDataListener());
        channel.unbind("any-event-2", receiveOrderListener());
        channel.unbind("any-event-3", logOutListener());
        channel.unbind("any-event-4", getOrderStatusListener());
        pusher.unsubscribe("*****");
        pusher.disconnect();
    }
}

public void restart() {
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(pusherAppKey)) {
        log.info("Restarting Pusher");
        disconnect();
        this.init(this.pusherAppKey);
    }
}

/*
 * private PusherOptions pusherOptions() { if (pusherOptions == null) {
 * pusherOptions = new PusherOptions();
 * pusherOptions.setMaxReconnectionAttempts(1000000); } return pusherOptions; }
 */

public boolean isConnected() {
    return isConnected;
}

private void setPusherStatus() {
    activeTime = new Date();
}

public void userLoggedOut() {
    this.isUserLoggedIn = false;
}
```

}

The maven dependency used is

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pusher</groupId>
        <artifactId>pusher-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Can anyone please have a look and let me know the issue with the code or dependency or any property I am missing while making connection to the server ? TIA.